# Does $ H^1 (X , \mathcal{O}_X^{ \ * }) $ represent the following moduli functor?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology, intersection-theory, moduli-space

We know that Picard's group of a compact manifold $X$, denoted $\mathrm{Pic} (X)$ is the group of isomorphism classes of holomorphic line bundles, with the tensor product operation.

We also know that there is a natural isomorphism as follows:
$$ \mathrm{Pic} (X) \simeq H^1 (X, \mathcal{O}_{X}^{ \ *} ) $$
I would like to know if it is possible to extend the isomorphism above into a bijection  that characterizes the notion of moduli problem as follows :
$$ F(T) = \{ \ \text{holomorphic line bundles over} \ \ T \ \} / \sim_{ \mathrm{iso} } \ \simeq \mathrm{Hom} (T , H^1 (X , \mathcal{O}_X^{ \ * } )) $$
such that : $ H^1 (X,\mathcal{O}_X^{ \ * } ) $ is the fine or the coarse moduli space representing the moduli functor $ F $ ? If it is not the case, could you tell me why in details please ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I presume $T$ is a scheme. What does the right hand side ($\mathrm{Hom}(T, \mathrm{H}^1(X,\mathcal{O}_X^*))$) mean?

Comment: @Mohan : The right hand side is the set of morphisms of schemes from the scheme $ T $ to the group scheme $ H^1 (X , \mathcal{O}_X^* ) $, no ? Can we endow the group $ H^1 (X , \mathcal{O}_X^* ) $ with the group scheme structure ?

Comment: $H^1(X, \mathcal{O}_X^{\times})$ is just a group (the Picard group). The Picard group can be upgraded to a scheme but it takes some extra work to do so: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_group#Picard_scheme

Comment: Thank you @Qiaochu Yuan, :-) , but i prefer to endow $ H^1 (X, \mathcal{O}_X^* ) $ with the group scheme structure as a sheaf cohomology group, not as the Picard group. Can we do that ?

Comment: Typically, the group scheme as you suggest is the product of $Pic^0$ with a discrete group. So, if $T$ is connected, might as well restrict your attention to the Picard scheme (which is an abelian variety in the projective normal case) and well understood. If $X$ is not compact, it is not a scheme in general.

Comment: What is the relationship between $T$ and $X$ ? I mean, you want a natural isomorphism $F(T)\simeq Hom(T,Pic(X))$ but the left hand side does not depend on $X$ whereas the right hand side does.

Comment: @Mohan : Thank you for your answer.  :-)

Comment: @Roland : Yes, thank you, i made a big mistake. In fact, i look for an object $M$ solution of the following moduli problem : $ F(T) = \{ \text{ holomorphic line bundles over} \ \  T  \} / \sim_{ \mathrm{iso} } \simeq \mathrm{Hom} ( T,M ) $.

Comment: There is an obvious obstruction : $Pic(X)$ is usually not a sheaf whereas if $M$ is any scheme then $Hom(X,M)$ is a sheaf (in $X$ for the Zariski topology). More precisely, if $v\in Pic(X)$, then almost by definition $v$ is locally trivial, but if $Pic(X)$ where a sheaf, it would imply that $v=0$. On the other hand, if $v\in Hom(X,M)$, then if $v$ is locally trivial, then $v$ is trivial. This is really the difference between a $H^0$ and a $H^1$. The problem is that locally, a holomorphic bundle has a lot of isomorphisms.